# Comparing structure equality of lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket, equivalence

How can I check the structural equality of two lists in Scheme?  For example, `(a (b) (c d))` is equal to `(a b (c d) (e f g))`, and `(a b)` is equal to `(a b c)`. The *data* content of the lists does not matter, only the structural hierarchy of the nested lists within, that is, the number of sublists, and the number of sublists of those sublists, and so on.

I made a function called `eqStruct` that takes two lists as arguments. It is supposed to count the number of sublists in each list, `a` and `b`, and then return a boolean. The function looks at each element of list `a`, and then each element of list `b`. It uses `c` and `d` as counters for the number of sublists in `a` and `b` respectively, and these are incremented when `atom?` returns false when called on an element of the list. After each time the first atom of the list is looked at, the list is set to equal itself without its first item (list-tail),  and the `unless` loops terminate when the whole lists 'a and 'b have been looked at.

```
(define (eqStruct 'a 'b)

    (define c 0)
    (define d 0)

    (define (atom? x) (not (pair? x)))

    (unless (null? a)
         (unless (atom? (first a)) (set! c (+ c 1))
         (set! a (list-tail a 1))
    )
    (unless (null? b)
         (unless (atom? (first b)) (set! d (+ d 1))
         (set! b (list-tail b 1))
    )

    (eq? c d)
)
```

That final line is supposed to be a return statement sort of, because I want the function to be a predicate and return whether the lists are of equal structure, a boolean value, but I was not sure how to make that happen, or if I was even thinking about this problem the right way.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by structural equality?  it's not clear to me how  "(a (b) (c d)) is equal to (a b (c d) (e f g)) and (a b) is equal to (a b c)".

Comment: sure, both examples are lists containing two nested sublists, the number of elements in the list and each sublist are irrelevant

Comment: So you could say that they're structurally equivalent because `(a (b) (c d))` projects to `(()())` and `(a b (c d) (e f g))` also projects to `(()())`?  Is this correct?  I guess you could say that `(()())` is their structure, and they have the same structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your approach

Your code (as well as your comments about it) point to some misconceptions about certain Racket constructs.

A big issue is that `unless` is not a looping construct;  it simply conditionally executes some code.  E.g., if you evaluate `(unless (= 1 2) (display 'x))`, you don't print `x` forever, but just print it once.  This means that the code you've got won't be doing what you expect it to.

However, if we assume that was (so that we understand what your code was *trying* to do), you've got a reasonable idea.  You're trying to iterate down the list `a` and count up how many elements it has that are lists.

```
    (unless (null? a)
         (unless (atom? (first a)) (set! c (+ c 1))
         (set! a (list-tail a 1))
    )
```

This is a fine idea *if* your lists are always going to be just one layer deep.  For instance, you'd check `((a b) c)` and `((a) b c)` correctly, but you wouldn't get `((a (b)) c)` (which has structure `((())())`) and `(((a) (b)) c)` (which has structure `((()())())` right.  If you just wanted to check whether `a` and `b` had the same number of elements that were lists, though (and if `unless` were a looping construct), you'd be on the right track.

### A slightly different (but similar) approach

The general approach that you're taking in trying to extract some value that represents the structure of the list (in your case, a number) from each of the input lists and comparing those representative values, is a good one.  I think that you just need to use a slightly different representative value, and to compare them a little bit differently (`eq?` is fine for your case, I think, but the representative value I have in mind needs `equal?`).

Note that, given the way they're defined, structures can be compared with `equal?`.  Given that observation, I think the easiest way to do this is probably to write a procedure that takes a list and returns its canonical structure.  Also notice that by using `list?` in the inner `if`, we properly handle cases like `((a b) ())` which has a structure of `(() ())`.

```
(define (structure list)
  (if (null? list)
      list
      (if (list? (car list))
          (cons (structure (car list)) (structure (cdr list)))
          (structure (cdr list)))))
```

```
> (structure '(a (b) (c d)))
(() ())
> (structure '((a b) ()))
(() ())
```

Then, to compare the structures of two lists, you can just get the structures of the two lists and compare them.

```
(define (structure-equal? list1 list2)
  (equal? (structure list1)
          (structure list2)))
```

```
> (structure-equal? '(a b) '(a b c))
#t
> (structure-equal? '(a (b) (c d)) '(a b (c d) (e f g)))
#t
```

Understanding how why `equal?` works on the structures shouldn't be too hard, but understanding *how* `structure` works is more important.  Let's look at it more closely

```
(define (structure list)
  (if (null? list)
      list ; or '()
      (if (list? (car list))                                    
          (cons (structure (car list)) (structure (cdr list)))
          (structure (cdr list)))))
```

We're assuming that the `list` that comes in is, in fact, a list.  This means that it's *either* the empty list `()` (so `(null? list)` is true), or else it's a pair that has a `car` and `cdr`.  The structure of the empty list is obviously the empty list, so we can just return `list` (because it's empty).  The other case is more complicated;  `list` is a pair whose `car` is some value and whose `cdr` is the rest of the list.  If the `car` is also a list, then it adds something to the structure of `list`, but if it's not, then it's just some element and doesn't contribute to the structure of the list.  More specifically, when `list` is the pair `(x . y)`:

- if `x` is a list, then the structure of `(x . y)` is `(<structure of x> . <structure of y>)`
- if `x` is not a list, then the structure of `(x . y)` is `<structure of y>`.

This should explain the logic inside the inner `if` (we create a pair `(a . b)` with `(cons a b)`).

Comment: that was a great explanation, including the evaluation of my misconceptions, I didn't realize unless was not a looping construct. thank you.