# Recursive algorithm to check nested lists if they are same or similar

Tags: python, algorithm, nested-lists

I need an `algorithm` on `python` to check if two lists have same structure.

For instance,
`[0, [0, 0]]` and `["", ["", ""]]` - absolutely same.

`[0, [0, 0]]` and `[["", ""], ""]` - same, but reversed.

`[0, 0, [0]]` and `["", "", ["", ""]]` or `["", [""]]`- depths are same, but lengths are different.

`[[[0]]]` and `[[""]]` - first is deeper.

Can this problem be solved with recursion?

or

Is there any ready modules / frameworks for python to do that?

To get structure as a tree with/without lengths of every node?

Thank you in advance.

Here you are my code, but it is not completed.

I don't know how to save the whole recursion path and in which format.

Please ignore any dictionaries, only the sequences are of interest. Strings are not considered as sequences, I will consider them as indivisible simple elements.

```
def recursion(obj):
    if type(obj) in ["<class 'list'>", "<class 'tuple'>", "<class 'set'>"]:
        for i in obj:
            recursion(i)
    else:
        pass
        # WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?
    return # WHAT SHOULD IT RETURN?
```

Comment: Yes, this problem can be solved with recursion. You have to specify what do you mean by having the same structure. Do you mean having the same content independently of order (based on your "reversed" example)? Or being exactly equal? What about `[()]` and `[[]]`? Do these have the same structure or not?

Comment: @nonDucor, with "same structure" I means that they iterable, have or not same length, have nested objects at the same position in sequence or can be called by same index. `tuple` or `list` or `set` is not important, because I am not going to change them or add / remove values.

Comment: Do you mean same structure in the sense of: [Comparing structure equality of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391831/comparing-structure-equality-of-lists)

Comment: Every problem that can be solved containing a loop can also be solved using recursion. And every problem solution can be put in a loop with one iteration, so "YES IT CAN BE SOLVED WITH RECURSION". Post what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: @MrSmith42, I added my code.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to compare the string representation of the lists with `re` - keep the `[`, `]`, `,`  as is and "remove" the other elements for comparison.

```py
a = [0, [0, 0]]
b = ["", ["", ""]]
re.sub(r'[^\[\], ]', '', str(b)) == re.sub(r'[^\[\], ]', '', str(a))
# True

c = [0, [0, 0]]
d = [["", ""], ""]
re.sub(r'[^\[\], ]', '', str(d)) == re.sub(r'[^\[\], ]', '', str(c))
# False

e = [0, 0, [0]]
f = ["", "", ["", ""]]
re.sub(r'[^\[\], ]', '', str(e)) == re.sub(r'[^\[\], ]', '', str(f))
# False
```

Comment: Thanks. What if there are not only  `lists` but also `tuples` and `sets`?

Comment: is it right? `r'[^\[\(\{\]\)\}, ]`

Comment: Well, the regex will get all the brackets but for it to work, you will need to go a step further and substitute all brackets with one kind - otherwise `[()]` will  not be equal to `([])` for example

Answer (score 2):

Using the method from [Comparing structure equality of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391831/comparing-structure-equality-of-lists/19392560#19392560)

**Translating the code to Python from Scheme**

```
def struct_equal(lst1, lst2):
    def structure(lst):
        '''
            Recursive function to generate list structure
        '''
        if not lst:
            return []
        elif isinstance(lst, (list, tuple, set)):
            lst = list(lst)                  # allows handling of list, tuples, sets
            if isinstance(lst[0], list):
                return [structure(lst[0])] + structure(lst[1:])
            else:
                return structure(lst[1:])
        else:
            raise Exception("Expected type list, tuple or set")
        
    return structure(lst1) == structure(lst2)
```

**Tests**

```
print(struct_equal([1], [1, 2, 3]))                  # True: works with lists
print(struct_equal([1], {1, 3}))                     # True: list and set
print(struct_equal([1], (1, 3)))                     # True: list and tuple
print(struct_equal([0, [0, 0]], ["", ["", ""]]))     # True
print(struct_equal([0, 0, [0]], ["", "", ["", ""]])) # True
print(struct_equal(["", "", ["", ""]], ["", [""]]))  # True
print(struct_equal([1, [2]], [3]))                   # False
```